# How to avoid expansion of single-quoted text in the `eval set... "$@"` for getopt?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcard, getopt, quoting

I'm using the conventional pattern for performing parameters decoding via getopt:

```
function mytest {
  eval set -- `getopt --options h --long help -- "$@"`
  echo "1:$1 2:$2"
}
```

But when I pass a single quoted string, it is actually expanded, for example:

```
$ mytest 'x * z'
1:-- 2:<list of files from current dir>
```

Strangely, it seems that only the specific structure `'<string> * <other_strings>'` triggers the behavior; similar structures don't:

```
$ mytest '* z'
1:-- 2:* z
$ mytest 'x *'
1:-- 2:x *
```

How can I perform evaluation as intended?

Comment: Note that `set -h` (`set -o hashall`) is not the same as `set --help`, it seems this is not the convetional way of reading optional parameters

Comment: Hello! Sorry, i don't understand the comment. `-h`/`--help` are not `getopt` command's options, instead, they are the function's options. in other words, using, for example, `eval set -- \`getopt --options u --long uselessoption -- "$@"\`` would still yield the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote your expansions to prevent globbing:

```
function mytest {
   eval set -- "`getopt --options h --long help -- "$@"`"
   echo "1:$1 2:$2"
}
```

Comment: This is also automatically suggested by [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net)

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate on why, without your suggestion, `mytest '* z'` is not expanded, while `mytest 'x * z'` is?

Comment: @Marcus `foo*` matches all files that starts with `foo`. `'*` matches all files that start with a single quote. You probably don't have any.

Answer (score 0):

since you are using in `eval`, so i don't see another option except to disable globs(the expansion takes place before the command is actually run.), i.e:

```
mytest ()
{
    set -f    # disable file name generation (globbing).
    eval set -- $(getopt --options h --long help -- "${@}")
    echo "1:${1} 2:${2}"
    set +f
}

$ mytest x * z
1:-- 2:x

$ mytest 'x * z'
1:-- 2:x * z

$ mytest ./*
1:-- 2:./config-err-reCeGT

$ mytest "./*"
1:-- 2:./*
```